# CSS tooltip getting cut off

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS tooltip that is being cut off when the hovered item is too close to the edge of the content area. See the links towards the bottom of this post: http://blog.betbright.com/top-stories/manchester-united-v-club-brugge-betting-preview/

Here is the code I'm using for the tooltip:

```
a.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltip span {
  position: absolute;
  width:110px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #00A1E0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.tooltip span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid #00A1E0;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltip span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -76px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Any solutions you can recommend to stop the tooltip being cut would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the `overflow` property on your `.entry-content` class to `visible` instead of `hidden`. Your current setting hides everything that does not fit within that `div`. Since your tooltip would be displayed partly outside your `.entry-content div`, a part is cut of unless you change the `overflow` property. So, your error is not in the tooltip, it's in a parent element.

Comment: I have the same issue but on a div that also needs the scrollbar! So I need overflow:auto or overflow:hidden to display the scrollbar but then my tooltip gets cut off aswel. So I basically need overflow only at the bottom or something? Any idea?

Comment: @Ayamei, it might be better to ask a new question, but you could try putting the tooltip outside the div that is causing your problems. That way the div can have `overflow: auto`, while your tooltip can be displayed properly.