# Tooltip gets cut off by div pure CSS

Tags: css

```css
.color-palette {
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
  max-height: 32vh;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  width: 90vw;
  bottom: 2.75rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0.75rem 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  }
    
button {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height: 0.9;
  width: 3.75rem;
  height: 3.75rem;
  margin: 0.45rem 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px grey, 0px 3px 0px 0px lightgrey,
    0px 8px 5px #999;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-family: "Comic Neue", cursive;
  width: 8.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  bottom: 110%;
  left: 35%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

span {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-palette">
    <button class="tooltip">
      <span class="tooltiptext">Cannot duplicate</span>
    </button>
    </div>
```

I got the tooltip code from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp.
I tried the answer here: [CSS tooltip getting cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052311/css-tooltip-getting-cut-off)

And have applied `overflow: visible` on my `color-palette` instead of `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;` but this happened:
[image]

Yes, the tooltip worked, but my buttons were already outside the div (.color-palette).
**I want this to work without removing the bottom arrow of the tooltip, without moving the tooltip downwards, without increasing the div to make the tooltip fit inside.** ***All I want is to make the tooltip overlap.*** What to do?

Comment: With this design of yours, how should the user gain access to the elements that are overflowing, i.e. the second row in the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing value from 110 to 95 in the class:

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
bottom: 95%;
}
```

Update:
change top value in class

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {

      top: 100%;
}
```

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ecxobpg3/38/

Comment: I tried it @fksjii. But is there any way that my tooltip will overlap the div without moving it downwards because I still want to have that bottom arrow of the tooltip.

Comment: What do you mean by bottom arrow of the tooltip?

Comment: The tooltip on your code doesn't have the arrow that points to the button; it's just a plain tooltip. But like what is shown on the result of my snippet above, it has a black arrow that points to my button. (Compare your tooltip to mine above.)

Comment: Yes, you got it @Fksjii. Thanks. But again, is there any way that my tooltip will overlap the div without moving it downwards?

Comment: Well, you can increase max-height of .color-pallete a bit, and set height to predefined size. Now everything fits.

Comment: I want this to work without removing the bottom arrow of the tooltip, without moving the tooltip downwards, without increasing the div to make the tooltip fit inside. All I want is to make the tooltip overlap. Could someone please do that? Help!